# Issues in selecting value from dropdown in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

How to select value from dropdown if ID of selector is repeat in signup page? I an writing test script in selenium web driver to retrieve the value from drop down control but always element not find exception is showing.

The code is,

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("cat_id"))); 
dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
```

The page targeted is : http://talentrack.in/register

Comment: Structure of the code like that <select id="cat_id" class="input-control req placeholder-color" onchange="return show_others(this.value);" data-message="required" name="cat_id"> select id is repeating twice in the page

Comment: Are you saying that multiple select element have the same id attribute?  If so, then this is malformed HTML, and you should tell you developers to fix it.  Or, are you pointing out that "cat_id" shows up twice within the select element above?  the id and name attributes are different attributes, and it's ok for them to have the same value.

Comment: @Yogesh Could you add some of your test code, and the HTML that it is targeting, to your question?

Comment: Thanks for replying, below is my code for selecting value Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("cat_id")));
   dropdown.selectByIndex(1); and link of the page that i m going to automate http://talentrack.in/register

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to your problem is using css, or xpath selectors:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#cat_id.req"))); 
dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
```

Before trying to write more code I highly recommend you learn how to use css and xpath selectors. Great place to start is [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/).

You should also consider installing FirePath Firefox plug-in, since it's a great tool to boost your learning speed.

Edit:

Here is my full code:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class test{

private WebDriver driver;
private WebDriverWait wait;

    @Test
    public void main() throws InterruptedException{     
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
    driver.get("http://talentrack.in/register");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#cat_id.req")));
    Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#cat_id.req"))); 
    dropdown.selectByIndex(5);
    Thread.sleep(5000);   
    driver.close();
    }}
```

Comment: Thanx for replying but still i am getting the same exception , org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#cat_id.req"}
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds, i have tried by all selector

Comment: Actually there is another hidden drop down control with the same selector id's on the page so may be it is interrupting the execution. here is the URL http://talentrack.in/register

Comment: CSS selectors work just fine for me - I updated my answer with a full code. (please don't use thread.sleep in our actual test)

Comment: @Yogesh the problem with your own code is, indeed, that there are 2 `<select>` tags in the page. The first is hidden, the second is not. The code you posted, `driver.findElement(By.id("cat_id"))` gets the first `<select>` element which is hidden. Selecting the 2nd element like so, `driver.findElements(By.id("cat_id"))[1]` ought to work.

Comment: Thanks for your useful reply and it is working. Thanks again